# Como compara um item com todos os outros itens da mesma lista (com dicionários dentro) de uma forma pythonica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Sou iniciante, galera. Só para constar!

Estou tentando comparar os itens de uma lista com dicionários e se eles são iguais, somar esses itens. Acho que com um exemplo, a ideia fica mais clara:

```
dados = [
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,},
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,}
]

print(f'Número de itens: {len(dados)}')

for dado in dados:
    print(f"{dado['Codigo']} = {dado['Valor']}")
```

A dúvida é: Se os valores de `Codigo` são iguais - Como somar esses valores em um item e retornar somente o valor total somado?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o intuito for apenas pedagógico podes fazer um *group by* 'manual', e ir somando:

```
dados = [
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,},
        {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,},
        {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00,}
]

dados_grouped = {}
for d in dados:
    dados_grouped[d['Codigo']] = dados_grouped.get(d['Codigo'], 0) + d['Valor']
```

Output de dados_grouped:

```
{1: 900.0, 2: 1200.0}
```

[Função get()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

Para coisas 'mais sérias' podes usar pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
dados_grouped = df.groupby('Codigo', as_index=False).sum().to_dict('records')
```

Output de dados_grouped:

```
[{'Codigo': 1.0, 'Valor': 900.0}, {'Codigo': 2.0, 'Valor': 1200.0}]
```

Mas é importante sabermos que existem [outras maneiras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328602/python-list-grouping-and-sum) de fazer isto em python.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Miguel. O intuito é pedagógico sim. Eu estou estudando listas e dicionários em Python e tentando aumentar o nível de dificuldade dos exercícios para fixar o aprendizado. Tentei fazer com o enumerate (acho que é esse o nome), mas ele somou e replicou meus valores somados (errei na lógica da condição). De todo modo, eu vou estudar o que vc me mandou, ok? Obrigado!

Comment: @MMelo, enumerate é desnecessário para este propósito. Bons estudos

Answer (score -2):

Pare para pensar... você precisa percorrer uma lista e somar os valores de chaves ja encontradas, correto?

Então você precisa de alguma maneira, durante a iteração da lista somar os valores por chaves.

Então está claro que você precisa ter uma nova estrutura de dados para armazenar esses valores somados, durante a iteração.

Para isso você pode utilizar uma estrutura de chave/valor(hashmap) e após executar as somas, você le essa nova estrutura e transforma na nova lista com os valores somados.

> Irei fazer em JS pois não conheço Python. E vejo que isso é falta de conhecimento em conceitos de estrutura de dados e programação básica do que uma dúvida sobre Python de fato

```js
const lista = [
  {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00},
  {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00},
  {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00},
  {"Codigo": 1, "Valor": 300.00},
  {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00},
  {"Codigo": 2, "Valor": 400.00}
];

const tempHashMap = {};

for (item of lista) {
  if (tempHashMap[item.Codigo] != null) {
    tempHashMap[item.Codigo] = tempHashMap[item.Codigo] + item.Valor;
  } else {
    tempHashMap[item.Codigo] = item.Valor
  }
}

const chavesDoHashMap = Object.keys(tempHashMap);

const novaLista = [];

for (chave of chavesDoHashMap) {
  novaLista.push({
    Codigo: chave,
    Valor: tempHashMap[chave]
  });
}

for (item of novaLista) {
  console.log(`${item.Codigo} = ${item.Valor}`)
}
```